New rows in Pandas Dataframe by considering combination of rows in the original dataframe and applying function to it
I have a Pandas dataframe df that looks like
Class_ID    Student_ID  theta
6           1           0.2
6           2           0.2
6           4           0.1
6           3           0.5
3           2           0.1
3           5           0.2
3           7           0.22
3           4           0.4
3           9           0.08

And I want to create a new dataframe by considering every Student_ID combination within the same Class_ID:
Class_ID    Student_ID_x    theta_x Student_ID_y    theta_y Student_Combination
6           1               0.20    2               0.20    1_2
6           1               0.20    4               0.10    1_4
6           1               0.20    3               0.50    1_3
6           2               0.20    4               0.10    2_4
6           2               0.20    3               0.50    2_3
6           3               0.50    4               0.10    3_4
3           2               0.10    5               0.20    2_5
3           2               0.10    7               0.22    2_7
3           2               0.10    4               0.40    2_4
3           2               0.10    9               0.08    2_9
3           5               0.20    7               0.22    5_7
3           5               0.20    9               0.08    5_9
3           7               0.22    9               0.08    7_9
3           4               0.40    5               0.20    4_5
3           4               0.40    7               0.22    4_7
3           4               0.40    9               0.08    4_9

My code for this is
df_new = df.merge(
    df,
    how='inner',
    on=['Class_ID']
)

df_new['Student_ID_x'] = df_new['Student_ID_x'].astype(int)
df_new['Student_ID_y'] = df_new['Student_ID_y'].astype(int)
df_new = df_new[df_new['Student_ID_x'] < df_new['Student_ID_y']]
df_new['Student_Combination'] = [f'{x}_{y}' for x, y in zip(df_new['Student_ID_x'], df_new['Student_ID_y'])]

and this works fine. However, for the new df df_new, I want to create a new column called feature for every Student_Combination by applying a function defined as follow:
def func(theta_x, theta_y, *theta):
 numerator = theta_x + theta_y
 denominator = 0
 for t in theta:
   denominator += t*t
 return numerator / denominator

where the *theta's are the theta's from the same Class_ID other than the original 2 students. So for example, for Student_Combination = 1_2 in Class 6, the feature equals (0.2+0.2)/(0.1^2+0.5^2) = 1.53846154
and the desired output looks like
Class_ID    Student_ID_x    theta_x Student_ID_y    theta_y Student_Combination  feature
6           1               0.20    2               0.20    1_2                  1.53846154
6           1               0.20    4               0.10    1_4                  1.03448276
6           1               0.20    3               0.50    1_3                  14
6           2               0.20    4               0.10    2_4                  1.03448276
6           2               0.20    3               0.50    2_3                  14
6           3               0.50    4               0.10    3_4                  7.5
3           2               0.10    5               0.20    2_5                  1.39664804
3           2               0.10    7               0.22    2_7                  1.5503876
3           2               0.10    4               0.40    2_4                  5.2742616
3           2               0.10    9               0.08    2_9                  1.28205128
3           5               0.20    7               0.22    5_7                  2.38095238
3           5               0.20    9               0.08    5_9                  1.28205128
3           7               0.22    9               0.08    7_9                  1.42857143
3           4               0.40    5               0.20    4_5                  9.25925926
3           4               0.40    7               0.22    4_7                  10.9929078
3           4               0.40    9               0.08    4_9                  4.87804878

And I have no idea how to do this. Thanks in advance

You can do this using a cartesian join and filter using query if your dataframe isn't too big.
df_m = df.merge(df, on='Class_ID').query('Student_ID_x < Student_ID_y')

df_m

Output:
    Class_ID  Student_ID_x  theta_x  Student_ID_y  theta_y
1          6             1     0.20             2     0.20
2          6             1     0.20             4     0.10
3          6             1     0.20             3     0.50
6          6             2     0.20             4     0.10
7          6             2     0.20             3     0.50
14         6             3     0.50             4     0.10
17         3             2     0.10             5     0.20
18         3             2     0.10             7     0.22
19         3             2     0.10             4     0.40
20         3             2     0.10             9     0.08
23         3             5     0.20             7     0.22
25         3             5     0.20             9     0.08
30         3             7     0.22             9     0.08
32         3             4     0.40             5     0.20
33         3             4     0.40             7     0.22
35         3             4     0.40             9     0.08

And, now much like your other question using we can set up your function to handle your logic:
def func(theta_x, theta_y, *theta):
    numerator = theta_x + theta_y
    denominator = 0
    for t in theta[0]:
        denominator += t*t
    return numerator / denominator

def fxs(x):
    s = pd.Series()
    for i, r in x.iterrows():

        # There's probably a easy way to handle this logic
        q = pd.concat([x[['Student_ID_x', 'theta_x']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-2]), 
                   x[['Student_ID_y' ,'theta_y']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-2])])
        q = q.drop_duplicates().set_index('Student_ID').squeeze()
        q.pop(r['Student_ID_x'].astype(int))
        q.pop(r['Student_ID_y'].astype(int))
        # But I think this works for you.

        s[i] = func(r['theta_x'], r['theta_y'], q.to_list())
    return s    

df_m['feature']  = df_m.groupby('Class_ID', group_keys=False).apply(fxs)
df_m

Output:
    Class_ID  Student_ID_x  theta_x  Student_ID_y  theta_y    feature
1          6             1     0.20             2     0.20   1.538462
2          6             1     0.20             4     0.10   1.034483
3          6             1     0.20             3     0.50  14.000000
6          6             2     0.20             4     0.10   1.034483
7          6             2     0.20             3     0.50  14.000000
14         6             3     0.50             4     0.10   7.500000
17         3             2     0.10             5     0.20   1.396648
18         3             2     0.10             7     0.22   1.550388
19         3             2     0.10             4     0.40   5.274262
20         3             2     0.10             9     0.08   0.724638
23         3             5     0.20             7     0.22   2.380952
25         3             5     0.20             9     0.08   1.282051
30         3             7     0.22             9     0.08   1.428571
32         3             4     0.40             5     0.20   9.259259
33         3             4     0.40             7     0.22  10.992908
35         3             4     0.40             9     0.08   4.878049


If you want an efficient method, don't use a custom function, pre-compute the sum of square of all your values per group, then subtract the sum of square of your two values.
You can also use janitor's conditional_join for an efficient merge:
import janitor

# step 1: perform the merge and flatten the MultiIndex
# you can also use your original method
def flatten(cols):
    return (cols.get_level_values(1)
           +pd.Index(np.where(cols.get_level_values(0)=='right',
                              '_x', '')))

out = (df.conditional_join(df, ('Class_ID', 'Class_ID', '=='),
                               ('Student_ID', 'Student_ID', '<'),
                           right_columns=['Student_ID', 'theta'])
         .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(flatten(x.columns), axis=1))
      )

# step 2: pre-compute the sum of squares per group
sums = df['theta'].pow(2).groupby(df['Class_ID']).sum()

# step 3: compute the sum and sum of squares per row
# apply the formula
out['feature'] = (
 out[['theta', 'theta_x']].sum(axis=1)
 .div(out['Class_ID'].map(sums)
      .sub(out[['theta', 'theta_x']].pow(2).sum(axis=1)))
)

Output:
0          6           1   0.20             2     0.20   1.538462
1          6           1   0.20             4     0.10   1.034483
2          6           1   0.20             3     0.50  14.000000
3          6           2   0.20             4     0.10   1.034483
4          6           2   0.20             3     0.50  14.000000
5          6           3   0.50             4     0.10   7.500000
6          3           2   0.10             5     0.20   1.396648
7          3           2   0.10             7     0.22   1.550388
8          3           2   0.10             4     0.40   5.274262
9          3           2   0.10             9     0.08   0.724638
10         3           5   0.20             7     0.22   2.380952
11         3           5   0.20             9     0.08   1.282051
12         3           7   0.22             9     0.08   1.428571
13         3           4   0.40             5     0.20   9.259259
14         3           4   0.40             7     0.22  10.992908
15         3           4   0.40             9     0.08   4.878049


You can apply func to calculate the feature for each pair of students in the dataframe by excluding their theta values and using the remaining theta values for the calculation.
def func(theta_x, theta_y, *theta):
    numerator = theta_x + theta_y
    denominator = 0
    for t in theta:
        denominator += t*t
    return numerator / denominator

def calculate_feature(row, original_df):
    class_id = row['Class_ID']
    thetas_in_class = original_df[original_df['Class_ID'] == class_id]
    theta_rest = thetas_in_class[~thetas_in_class['Student_ID'].isin([row['Student_ID_x'], row['Student_ID_y']])]['theta'].values
    return func(row['theta_x'], row['theta_y'], *theta_rest)

df_new['feature'] = df_new.apply(lambda row: calculate_feature(row, df), axis=1)

Output:
    Class_ID    Student_ID_x    theta_x Student_ID_y    theta_y Student_Combination feature
1   6   1   0.20    2   0.20    1_2 1.538462
2   6   1   0.20    4   0.10    1_4 1.034483
3   6   1   0.20    3   0.50    1_3 14.000000
6   6   2   0.20    4   0.10    2_4 1.034483
7   6   2   0.20    3   0.50    2_3 14.000000
14  6   3   0.50    4   0.10    3_4 7.500000
17  3   2   0.10    5   0.20    2_5 1.396648
18  3   2   0.10    7   0.22    2_7 1.550388
19  3   2   0.10    4   0.40    2_4 5.274262
20  3   2   0.10    9   0.08    2_9 0.724638
23  3   5   0.20    7   0.22    5_7 2.380952
25  3   5   0.20    9   0.08    5_9 1.282051
30  3   7   0.22    9   0.08    7_9 1.428571
32  3   4   0.40    5   0.20    4_5 9.259259
33  3   4   0.40    7   0.22    4_7 10.992908
35  3   4   0.40    9   0.08    4_9 4.878049

